# Splat parameters to a cmdlet without unrolling array

Tags: powershell

I have this cmdlet:

```
$dnstype = ,@("Primary","Secondary","Tertiary")
$dnsserver = ,@("192.168.1.11","192.168.1.12","192.168.150.13")

Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting -connection $connection -DNSServer $dnsserver -DNSServerType $dnstype
```

This works fine.

However, I need to splat the parameters, because I am adding parameters depending on the known state of the object (this is because some parameters result in a reset which I'm trying to avoid if possible).

When doing the following the DNS servers are not amended as they need to remain "unrolled" when sent to the cmdlet.

```
$dnstype = ,@("Primary","Secondary","Tertiary")
$dnsserver = ,@("192.168.1.11","192.168.1.12","192.168.150.13")

$NewDCHPv4Settings = @{
    Connection    = $connection
    InterfaceType = "Dedicated"
    OutVariable   = "IPv4Set"
    OutputType    = "Object"
    DNSName       = $ShortName.ToLower()
    ErrorAction   = "Stop"
    Verbose       = $true
}
# Check DNS and amend if required
if ($IPv4Settings.DNSServer -ne $dnsserver) {
    Write-Host "DNS server entries not correct, amending"
    $NewDCHPv4Settings.Add("DNSServer", $dnsserver)
    $NewDCHPv4Settings.Add("DNSServerType", $dnstype)
}

Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting @NewDCHPv4Settings
```

So the question - how do I add the unary arrays to the splat array so that the integrity is maintained and they process correctly?

As requested - here is the defintion:

```
Name          : Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting
ModuleName    : HPEiLOCmdlets
Module        : @{Name=HPEiLOCmdlets}
CommandType   : Cmdlet
Definition    : 
                Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting [-Connection] <Connection[]> -InterfaceType <string[]> [-SharedNetworkPortType <string[]>] [-SNPPort <int[]>] 
                [-VLANEnabled <string[]>] [-VLANID <int[]>] [-DNSName <string[]>] [-DomainName <string[]>] [-NICEnabled <string[]>] [-FullDuplex <string[]>] 
                [-LinkSpeedMbps <string[]>] [-DHCPEnabled <string[]>] [-DHCPv4Gateway <string[]>] [-DHCPv4DomainName <string[]>] [-DHCPv4DNSServer <string[]>] 
                [-DHCPv4WINSServer <string[]>] [-DHCPv4StaticRoute <string[]>] [-DHCPv4NTPServer <string[]>] [-IPv4Address <string[]>] [-IPv4SubnetMask <string[]>] 
                [-IPv4Gateway <string[]>] [-IPv4StaticRouteIndex <int[][]>] [-IPv4StaticRouteDestination <string[][]>] [-IPv4StaticRouteMask <string[][]>] 
                [-IPv4StaticRouteGateway <string[][]>] [-DNSServerType <string[][]>] [-DNSServer <string[][]>] [-RegisterDDNSServer <string[]>] [-PingGateway 
                <string[]>] [-RegisterWINSServer <string[]>] [-WINSServerType <string[][]>] [-WINSServer <string[][]>] [-iLONICAutoDelay <int[]>] [-iLONICFailOver 
                <string[]>] [-iLONICFailOverDelay <int[]>] [-iLONICAutoSelect <string[]>] [-iLONICAutoSNPScan <int[]>] [-OutputType <string>] [-Force] 
                [<CommonParameters>]

ParameterSets : {@{Name=__AllParameterSets; IsDefault=False; Parameters=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your array of arrays?  `,` in front of your array literal `@()`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The unary array construction operator prevents PowerShell from unrolling an array by wrapping the array into another array (which upon unrolling the outer array leaves the nested array intact).

Comment: `$NewDCHPv4Settings.Add("DNSServer", $dnsserver)` -> `$NewDCHPv4Settings['DNSServer'] = ,$dnsserver`

Comment: No luck there Ansgar - using your syntax adds it as an object and results in: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'DNSServerType'

Comment: So if `-DNSServer` and `-DNSServerType` require strings, why are you using arrays in the first place instead of modifying a string?

Comment: Because that's what's required - my top example is an exact copy of the example provided by HP to set the parameters.

To modify that setting requires that all parameters are passed at once. The "DNSServer" parameter designats the server IP address and the "DNSServerType" parameter, which has t be specififed at the same time contains the designation (Primary, Secondary or Tertiary).
I cant specify the parameters multiple times to set all 3 and cant run the cmdlet 3 times.
If you have a way to pass 3 separate strings at once in this context, I'm open to it.

Comment: @Scepticalist Did you change *both* parameters (the error is from `DNSServerType`, not `DNSServer`)? Did you try without the comma? Please update your question with the code you currently have and the error you're getting from that code. Also show the interface defintion of the cmdlet/function you're calling.

Comment: Yes - I changed both - the error simply is from the first failure as is usual.

Ok, this error message should explain things a bit and why an object won't work:
Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting : To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, -parameter value1,value2,value3

Comment: Updated my original post with the cmdlet definition. The code is correct to what I am currently using.

Comment: *"The unary array construction operator prevents PowerShell from unrolling an array by wrapping the array into another array (which upon unrolling the outer array leaves the nested array intact)."*, `$NewDCHPv4Settings = @{...}` is *not* an **array** but a **hashtable** therefore (afaik) it will not unroll embedded arrays as `$dnstype` and `$dnsserver`. In other words, you should indeed simply leave the comma's in front of arrays out as @TheIncorrigible1 purposed in the first comment (otherwise you indeed feed it with an .Net `System.Object[]` rather than a PowerShell array).

Comment: After some further rtesting it seems there was an issue with the iLO/logic rather than the splat technique here.
Many thanks everyone for your contributions. The upside is I learned a lot about splatting along the way.

Answer (score 0):

As in comments, my issue was being cause by the iLO itself/logic rather than the splat being incorrect. My original code does indeed work as intended:

```
$dnstype = ,@("Primary","Secondary","Tertiary")
$dnsserver = ,@("192.168.1.11","192.168.1.12","192.168.150.13")

$NewDCHPv4Settings = @{
    Connection    = $connection
    InterfaceType = "Dedicated"
    OutVariable   = "IPv4Set"
    OutputType    = "Object"
    DNSName       = $ShortName.ToLower()
    ErrorAction   = "Stop"
    Verbose       = $true
}
# Check DNS and amend if required
if ($IPv4Settings.DNSServer -ne $dnsserver) {
    Write-Host "DNS server entries not correct, amending"
    $NewDCHPv4Settings.Add("DNSServer", $dnsserver)
    $NewDCHPv4Settings.Add("DNSServerType", $dnstype)
}

Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting @NewDCHPv4Settings
```